# Compare column entry to every other entry in the same column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a Column of values in SQLite.

```
value
-----
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

For each value I would like to know how many of the other values are larger and display the result. E.g. For value 1 there are 4 entries that have higher values.

```
value | Count
-------------
  1   |   4
  2   |   3
  3   |   2
  4   |   1
  5   |   0
```

I have tried nested select statements and using the Count(*) function but I do not seem to be able to extract the correct levels. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in SQLite:

```
select value,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.value > t.value) as "count"
from t;
```

In most other databases, you would use a ranking function such as `rank()` or `dense_rank()`, but SQLite doesn't support these functions.